# Breitung-Candelon's Granger Causality in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a solution to perform a Breitung and Candelon's Granger causality test like in [Tastan](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1501500411) (2015) but with R.
I tried with the `grangers`' package but I am facing 2 issues :

- I get a frequency range of [0;0,5] instead of [0; π].
- the last threshold is different from the others.

Does someone know how to obtain the same results as the `bcgcausality` Stata function described in Tastan(2015) ?

---

Here's my output :

```
bc_test_uncond(Emploi.total, Dow.Jones, ic.chosen = "AIC", max.lag = 4, plot = F, type.chosen = "none", p = 0, conf = 0.95)
```

> $frequency  [1](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1501500411) 0.01388889 0.02777778 0.04166667 0.05555556 0.06944444
> 0.08333333  [7] 0.09722222 0.11111111 0.12500000 0.13888889 0.15277778 0.16666667 [13] 0.18055556 0.19444444 0.20833333 0.22222222 0.23611111 0.25000000 [19] 0.26388889 0.27777778 0.29166667 0.30555556 0.31944444 0.33333333 [25] 0.34722222 0.36111111 0.37500000 0.38888889 0.40277778 0.41666667 [31] 0.43055556 0.44444444 0.45833333 0.47222222 0.48611111 0.50000000
>
> $`F-threshold`  [1](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1501500411) **3.140438** 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438
> 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438  [9] 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 [17] 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 [25] 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 [33] 3.140438 3.140438 3.140438 **3.986269**